# Output to pdf not working with ReferenceClasses methods in R?

Tags: r, oop, reference-class

Output to pdf not working with ReferenceClasses methods in R?

This is an example taken from the ReferenceClasses R doc, with some minor
modification:

```
mEdit = setRefClass("mEdit", fields = list(data="matrix", edits="list"))
mEdit$methods(
    edit = function(i, j, value) {
        backup = list(i, j, data[i, j])
        data[i, j] <<- value
        edits <<- c(edits, list(backup))
        invisible(value)
    }
)
mEdit$methods(
undo = function() {
    prev = edits
    if(length(prev)) {
        prev = prev[[length(prev)]]
    }
    else {
        stop("No more edits to undo!")
    }
    edit(prev[[1]], prev[[2]], prev[[3]])
    length(edits) <<- length(edits) - 2
    invisible(prev)
}
)
mEdit$methods(
    show = function() {
        message("ClassName: ", classLabel(class(.self)))
        message("Data:")
        methods::show(data)
        message("Undo list length: ", length(edits))
    }
)
mEdit$methods(
    .DollarNames.mEdit = function(x, pattern) {
        grep(pattern, getRefClass(class(x))$methods(), value=TRUE)
    }
)

x = matrix(1:24, 3, 8)
xx = mEdit(data=x)
xx$edit(2,2,0)
xx$show()
xx$edit(3, 5, 1)
xx$show()
xx$undo()
xx$show()

mv = setRefClass(
"matrixViewer",
fields=c("viewerDevice", "viewerFile"),
contains="mEdit"
                 )
mv$methods(
    .DollarNames.mEdit = function(x, pattern) {
        grep(pattern, getRefClass(class(x))$methods(), value=TRUE)
    }
)

mv$methods(
    view = function() {
        ## dd = dev.cur();
        ## dev.set(viewerDevice)
        ## devAskNewPage(FALSE)
        image(
            data,
            main=paste("After", length(edits), "edits")
        )
        ## dev.set(dd)
    }
)
mv$methods(
    edit = function(i,j, value) {
        callSuper(i,j, value)
        view()
    }
)
mv$methods(
    initialize = function(file="./mv.pdf", ...) {
        viewerFile <<- file
        ## pdf(viewerFile)
        ## viewerDevice <<- dev.cur()
        ## dev.set(dev.prev())
        callSuper(...)
    }
)
mv$methods(
    finalize = function() {
        dev.off(viewerDevice)
    }
)


x = matrix(rnorm(64, 0, 34), 8, 8)
xx = mv(file="/tmp/x.pdf", data=x)
xx$edit(2,2,0)
xx$edit(3, 5, 1)
xx$edit(4, 4, 2.3)
xx$undo()
xx$view()
```

Note that I have commented out those lines concerning switch
    of output devices, so it uses the default device all through,
    otherwise when the `view` method
    is called, the plot is not written to the pdf file at all.
    Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `rm` on `xx` and then call garbage collection. `finalize` will then be called which will invoke `dev.off` and the pdf will be written. This assumes everything is uncommented.

```
rm(xx)
gc()
```

Also your `.DollarNames` should be

```
.DollarNames.mEdit = function(x, pattern) {
    grep(pattern, getRefClass(class(x))$methods(), value=TRUE)
}

.DollarNames.matrixViewer = function(x, pattern) {
    grep(pattern, getRefClass(class(x))$methods(), value=TRUE)
}
```

and are not `methods` of the Reference class. They are external functions seperate to the Reference classes.

So the main takeaway here is that `finalize` is not called until the object is garbage collected.